# Mule XMPP Transport - XMPPException: SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized

Tags: mule, xmpp

I'm trying to connect Mule ESB 3.9 with  Cisco Jabber server using the XMPP Transport. I'm following the Mule documentation  [XMPP Transport Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/xmpp-transport-reference#transport-info)

And using the same example from there:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xmpp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmpp"
  xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmpp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmpp/current/mule-xmpp.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/current/mule-stdio.xsd">

<xmpp:connector name="xmppConnector" host="localhost" user="theUser" password="secret"/>

<flow name="stdio2xmpp">
    <stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN"/>
    <xmpp:outbound-endpoint type="CHAT" recipient="otheruser@localhost"/>
</flow>

<flow name="xmpp2stdio">
    <xmpp:inbound-endpoint type="CHAT" from="otheruser@localhost"/>
    <xmpp:xmpp-to-object-transformer/>
    <stdio:outbound-endpoint system="OUT"/>
</flow>
```

I'm setting the host, user and password correctly, actually I have a nodejs app where I'm able to connect and send messages using node-xmpp with the same credentials.

However in Mule the exception 
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException: SASL authentication PLAIN failed: not-authorized is thrown.

This is my first time that I'm working with the XMPP protocol, so any help to sort this out  work is appreciated

Jorge

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?